# Sublime text 3 - Predawn theme error message

Tags: sublimetext3

i've installed the [Predawn theme](https://github.com/jamiewilson/predawn) for ST3 a few weeks back and it worked like a charm for a while. I recently tried to [sync my configuration folder with Dropbox](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing) and something went very wrong (although i'm not a 100% sure that the sync is trhe cause). Now each time i start, save, change to another color scheme or else, i get this error message:

> Error loading colour scheme Packages/User/Color
>   Highlighter/themes/predawn (SL).tmTheme: Unable to open
>   Packages/User/Color Highlighter/themes/predawn (SL).tmTheme

I've tried to switch back, [like this](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html) to a fresh install with no positive result. The error message keeps appearing.

Answer (score 0):

People (like me) should better read error messages. The color highlighter plugin was missing. It's all fine now.